# OpenSSL verify_callback and SSL_connect

Tags: c++, linux, openssl

The `SSL_CTX_set_verify()` and `SSL_set_verify()` calls can be used to set the `verify_callback()` function for the underlying context and ssl, respectively. Here is a snippet from the documentation of `verify_callback()`:

> The return value of verify_callback controls the strategy of the
>   further verification process. If verify_callback returns 0, the
>   verification process is immediately stopped with "verification failed"
>   state. If SSL_VERIFY_PEER is set, a verification failure alert is sent
>   to the peer and the TLS/SSL handshake is terminated. If
>   verify_callback returns 1, the verification process is continued. If
>   verify_callback always returns 1, the TLS/SSL handshake will not be
>   terminated with respect to verification failures and the connection
>   will be established.

Now to my question. If I setup the `verify_callback()` (along with any other necessary OpenSSL setup calls, certificates, etc.), then call `SSL_connect()`, is it safe to assume that any call to `verify_callback()` for connection establishment purposes will return before the return of the `SSL_connect()` call?

It appears to me that this is a safe assumption since the documentation states that this callback is what determines whether a connection will be established or not. Therefore, the callback will directly affect the return value of the `SSL_connect()` call. Can anyone confirm/deny this assumption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Assuming that you are interested only in TCP connection* : short answer: **yes**, long answer: *it depends*:

- If you connect in ***blocking mode*** - always **yes**
- If you connect in ***non-blocking mode*** - `SSL_connect` may return -1 during the process of establishing connection. In this case you should call `SSL_get_error` and check what the problem was (if it returns `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` or `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE` you need to repeat the `SSL_connect` call). If you need to repeat the call - then the answer is **no** (`verify_callback` will be called somewhere between first and last `SSL_connect` call).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I assume your answer implies the following: If the underlying socket is non-blocking, and `SSL_connect` returns successfully (even after multiple repetitions to the call), then this means that the `verify_callback` was called and returned before the `SSL_connect` returns?

Comment: @HK - yes, in case of non-blocking socket `verify_callback` wil be called somewhere between first and last `SSL_connect` call.

Comment: One more thing. Do you mind telling me whether this is documented somewhere? Or is it out of experience using OpenSSL?

Comment: @HK - both from experience (I wrote quite a lot of code using OpenSSL) and from looking at the OpenSSL source code.